# particular solution to $y^4 -2y'' +y = xe^x $

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

I am trying to find the particular solution to the $y^4 -2y'' +y = xe^x $
and currently am misunderstanding what to do.

My steps:

the polynomial operator concerned is $p(s)= s^4 -2s^2 + 1 $
which  0 at 1:  $p(1) = 0 $

so now i know that the solution will be something like:

$y_p = x^2(Ax + B)e^x$ 
where the parentheses show that it is a linear operator on the last coefficient.

I am told to use the exponential shift rule on $e^x$ so i believe that it is this:

$y_p = x^2e^x(Ax + B + 1)$

but i'm not sure if this is correct or where to go from here. because now the operator is operating on a coefficient of 1?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

$$y^4 -2y'' +y = xe^x$$
The caracteristic polynomial is
$$\implies r^4-2r^2+1=0$$
$$(r^2-1)^2=0 $$
$$(r-1)^2(r+1)^2=0 \implies r=1,-1$$
The solution to the homogeneous equation is 
$$y_h=c_1e^x+c_2xe^x+c_3e^{-x}+c_4xe^{-x}$$
for the particular solution try
$$y_p=(Ax^3+Bx^2)e^x$$

---

***Another method***

$$y^4 -2y'' +y = xe^x$$
$$y^4 -y''-y'' +y = xe^x$$
$$(y'' -y)''-(y'' -y) = xe^x$$
Substitute $z=y''-y$
$$z''-z=xe^x$$
it's linear of second order

Comment: I am slightly confused because the book says try $ Y_p=x^2(Ax+B)e^x$

Comment: its the same as the particular solution I wrote @entercaspa  $$x^2(Ax+B)e^x=(Ax^3+Bx^2)e^x$$

Comment: i see that now, i did not know that was a rule of linear operators

Comment: differentiate and plug that in the original equation to get the value of A and B @entercaspa

Comment: so is that the same as $y_p = x^2e^x(Ax+B+1)$ following the exponential shift rule?

Comment: could yoi please walk me through how I differentiate and plug in to the original equation?

Comment: there is a methof of direct integration that could certainly work but I think you are asked to evaluate $y'_p$ and $y''_p$ you just differentiate wrt x @entercaspa

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80256/discussion-between-entercaspa-and-isham).