# $x_p$ of a ordinary differential equation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find the particular solution to the $y^{(4)} -2y'' +y = xe^x $
and currently am misunderstanding what to do.

My steps:

the polynomial operator concerned is $p(s)= s^4 -2s^2 + 1 $
which  0 at 1:  $p(1) = 0 $

so now i know that the solution will be something like:

$y_p = (Ax^3 + Bx^2)e^x$ 
where the parentheses show that it is a linear operator on the last coefficient.

so far I think that my method is to differentiate this four times and collect up the terms of each $y_p$ according to the original equation and see what A and B are equal to.

I assume this is okay to do with linear operators?

$y_p' = (Ax^3 + Bx^2)e^x + (3Ax^2 + 2Bx)e^x$

$y_p'' = (Ax^3 +(6A + B)x^2 + (4B + 6A)x + 2B)e^x$

$y_p''' = (Ax^3 +(9A +B)x^2 + (18A +6B)x + (6A + 6B))e^x$

$y_p'''' = (Ax^3 +(12A +B)x^2 + (36A +8B)x + (24A + 12B))e^x$

which then gives me an equation of $A-2A +A = 1$ which is wrong because this is the equation for the first term of the particular solution. Can anyone please help me take it from here?

Comment: You should add new details to previous post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2854072/particular-solution-to-y4-2y-y-xex-using-undetermined-coefficients

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2853961/particular-solution-to-y4-2y-y-xex?rq=1

Comment: @Moo i assume you just collected the terms as I tried to, if you could explain the first part of the equation it would be lovely! thank you very much for this

Comment: okay thought so, this means that it is just an error in my part on the differentiating, thank you very much i appreciate the support